# How to set hyperparameter (learning_rate) schedule in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, hyperparameters

What is the way to schedule hyper-parameters in TensorFlow?

Namely, for the sake of reproducibility I would like to implement a ResNet (you name one) using suggested learning rate schedule {0: 0.1, 1: 1., 100: 0.01, 150: 0.001}, or enable the weight decay only after first few initial epoch.

For example, tensorpack provides an optionas follows:

```
ScheduledHyperParamSetter('learning_rate', [(1, 0.1), (82, 0.01), (123, 0.001), (300, 0.0002)])
```

How can that be done in native TF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it wasn't that hard

```
    schedule = {1: 0.1, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.3, 4: 0.4, 100: 0.01, 150: 0.001}
    schedule = sorted(config.lr_schedule.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])

    boundaries = [num_train_iter * int(x[0]) for x in schedule]
    rates = [x[1] for x in schedule]
    rates = rates[:1] + rates  # 
    assert len(boundaries) + 1 == len(rates)

    learning_rate = tf.train.piecewise_constant(tf.cast(global_step, tf.int32), boundaries, rates)
```